# intellij idea file encoding

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Dokker in Intellij idea.

I have a problem with log file encoding in Intellij idea.

I created a python project in which there is only one line of code that prints the Russian word "Привет"

I am running a project in Docker. In the log file, shows **RџСЂРёРІРµС**

This kind of issue is only observed by Intellij idea. There is no such problem Visual Studio Code.

I changed the encoding and it does not help https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/encoding.html#single-file

**How to fix this problem?**

Comment: Does it help if you add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in `Help | Edit Custom VM Options` and restart IntelliJ IDEA?